# Android indeterminate progress as ImageView source

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar, imageview, progress

I have an `ImageView` for which I'd like to show an indeterminate progress spinner until the image has been loaded. Ideally, I'd like to point to the drawable itself from my layout xml file, and then simply swap the image in code.

Here's the xml for the drawable; all it shows is a static image that doesn't spin.

```
<animated-rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="500" />
```

I've also tried it with just the `<rotate>` root tag and the result is the same. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: how you call your animation in code?

Comment: Do i have to call it from code? It can't just be an xml living in res/drawable and the imageview will know to animate it?

Comment: yes you have to call it from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem in a much simpler way. I have a `FrameLayout` with two children: the custom `ImageView`, and an indeterminate `ProgressBar`. When the image finishes loading, I make the `ProgressBar` gone.

Answer (score 0):

Load the Animation from your anim folder and than call startAnimation to play it:

```
final ImageView ivRotate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_rotate);
Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_picture);
ivRotate.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: This rotates the entire `ImageView`, including the background. How do I make only the source image (currently the spinner) rotate?

Comment: @Karakuri: Make the background transparent.

Comment: That still rotates the entire View, not the image itself.